# what's the path of msbuild in vsts

Tags: build, msbuild, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task

asp.net web form project needs to be migrated to vsts. The project uses python script  to build and publish. In the code it calls the msbuild.exe. However, I am confused how to refer msbuild location in vsts repalcing previous location in python file..

Comment: Do you mean what is the location in the Hosted 2017 agent?

Comment: yes  Shayki Abramczyk. The location of it  in vsts.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/msbuild?view=vsts in this link I could see that there is a parameter  #msbuildLocation: # Optional. So I believe there might be a location/path of msbuild.exe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the location from Hosted Agent `Capabilities`.

1. Navigate to
   `https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_settings/agentpools`
2. Select the specific Pool and Agent(`Hosted VS2017` in your scenario)
3. Switch to `Capabilities` tab

For example, below is the MSBuild location in the **Hosted VS2017 agent**:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I will give a try.

Comment: I don't suppose there's a "predefined variable" I can use for this, is there?