# Config Transform in Azure DevOps

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops

I would like to use a visual studio proj file to transform xml files. I am following this article. http://sedodream.com/2010/04/26/ConfigTransformationsOutsideOfWebAppBuilds.aspx . This works for me locally, however when deploying the application on Azure DevOps it fails. It cannot find Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll. How do I set up a build task that will only transform the config files.

```
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <UsingTask TaskName="TransformXml"
             AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll"/>
    <Target Name="Build">
        <TransformXml Source="Web.config"
                      Transform="Web.Release.config"
                      Destination="Web.Production.config" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out to be an easy fix. It was an old build so that the hosted agent. Just had to change it to the Hosted VS2017 agent.

Comment: Hi, glad to know the issue has been solved. And thanks for sharing your solution, you can mark it as answer which benefit other members with similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

> AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll"/>

I think that's why the issue happens. For a vs2017 agent, you need to change the v10.0 to v15.0, so that the msbuild tool can find the assembly.

Also, as for vs2017, make sure you set the correct msbuild tool path in VSTS like [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52810150/whats-the-path-of-msbuild-in-vsts).

Comment: Sorry I missed adding my code earlier. I am using v15 instead of v10. I will check the path as you mentioned.