# Self-hosted agent (for Azure pipelines) using incorrect version of MSBuild

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops, msbuild, azure-pipelines-build-task

When building a solution using Azure's self-hosted build agents, I am explicitly setting the MSBuild version to be used, both in the MSBuild task in the pipeline, but also as part of the build arguments.

However, when the build is executing, it is using a much older version of MSBuild but I'm not able to determine a cause. The Azure settings are so;

[image: Azure build settings]

I have also verified that it *is* `v12.0` that is running as I can see in the logs in  `diagnostic mode`;

```
39>GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
   Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all 
   output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
   CoreCompile:
     C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Csc.exe 
     /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702 
     /nostdlib+ /platform:x86 
     /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 
     /highentropyva+ 
     /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.8\mscorlib.dll" 
     /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.8\System.Configuration.dll" 
     /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.8\System.Core.dll" 
     /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.8\System.dll" 
     /reference:C:\Users\<user>\Files\BuildAgents\ProdAgent1\_work\12\s\src\packages\Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Owin.ResourceAuthorization.1.1.0\lib\net45\Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Owin.ResourceAuthorization.dll 
     /debug:pdbonly /filealign:512 
     /optimize+ /out:obj\Release\Common.Security.dll 
     /subsystemversion:6.00 
     /target:library 
     /utf8output Authorization\CoreAuthorizationManager.cs 
                 Configuration\FrameworkMode.cs 
                 Configuration\IdentityConstants.cs                      
                 Configuration\LoggingConfig.cs                      
                 Configuration\SecurityConfig.cs                      
                 Configuration\Settings\ConfigFileLoggingSettingsProvider.cs                      
                 Configuration\Settings\ConfigFileSecuritySettingsProvider.cs                      
                 Configuration\Settings\ILoggingSettingsProvider.cs                      
                 Configuration\Settings\ISecuritySettingsProvider.cs                      
                 Configuration\Settings\LoggingSettings.cs                      
                 Configuration\Settings\SecuritySettings.cs                      
                 Configuration\Settings\SettingsHelper.cs                      
                 Configuration\TokenClientConfig.cs                      
                 Configuration\WebClientConfig.cs                      
                 Diagnostics\ILogger.cs                      
                 Diagnostics\Logger.cs                      
                 Diagnostics\LogHelper.cs                      
                 Diagnostics\LogHelper.Exceptions.cs                      
                 Extensions\ClaimsExtensions.cs                      
                 Extensions\ResourceAuthorizationContextExtensions.cs                      
                 Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs                      
                 SecurityFrameworkException.cs "C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.8.AssemblyAttributes.cs"
```

I have also checked the user's and system environment variables to see if there was anything set and there is nothing I can find (in the code or environment), that explicitly references MSBuild version `12.0`. How do I force the agent to use `17.0`?

The `yaml` for the MSBuild task is;

```
steps:
- task: MSBuild@1
  displayName: 'MSBuild solution src/{sln}.sln'
  inputs:
    solution: src/{sln}.sln
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
    msbuildArguments: '/verbosity:normal/p:VisualStudioVersion=17.0 /m:1 /p:GenerateSerializationAssemblies=Off /p:Platform="Auto"'
    clean: true
    createLogFile: true
```

### UPDATE

I've applied several suggestions below in the comments and have gotten the following results;

**1 What was tried**

Installing a new build agent

**1 Result**

Using the latest version of the Azure agent, and installing it to the same azure pool, still results in the agent picking MSBuild V`12`, instead of the configured setting in the pipeline task.

---

**2 What was tried**

Changing the build task to a Visual Studio build.

**2 Result**

The build still picks MSBuild V`12` to do the build itself.

---

**3 What was tried**

Specifying the location of `msbuild.exe`, instead of specifying the version.

**3 Result**

This *did* pick the correct `msbuild.exe` at the location specified, but now the build breaks looking for a `targets` file... in the v`12` MSBuild folder. The error message is;

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(67,3): 
Error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.NETFramework.props" was not found. 
Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration "Microsoft.NETFramework.props" is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
```

---

**4 What was tried**

Running a Repair on the Visual Studio version

**4 Result**

No effect. Still picking incorrect version of `msbuild.exe`

---

**5 What was tried**

Manually running the correct version of `msbuild.exe` against the solution the agent downloaded

**5 Result**

Build fails...but does actually build most of the projects. It fails on 9/~60 projects in the solution. The message for each of the failed projects looks like;

```
"C:\agent\_work\1\s\src\{sln}.sln" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\agent\_work\1\s\src\Tools\MakeTestSmartCard\MakeTestSmartCard.csproj" (default target) (133) ->
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(67,3): 
error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.NETFramework.props" was 
   not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration "Microsoft.NETFramework.props" 
   is correct, and that the file exists on disk. 
[C:\agent\_work\1\s\src\Tools\MakeTestSmartCard\MakeTestSmartCard.csproj]
```

It *almost* works. But there's still something redirecting part of the build.

---

**6 What was tried**

Creating a basic test project and running `msbuild` against that.

**6 Result**

This works and completes successfully. It suggests that there may be something in the solution or solution's build configuration that is causing the build agent to select v12 of `msbuild`.

Comment: just to be clear, this is an agent from the azure pool? I was bit on the wrong foot with the term "self-hosted"

Comment: @promicro, it's a VM that we built and then configured to run as a build agent on azure as part of a build pool (hence the term "self-hosted"). This was needed as there were 3rd party dependencies that a pre-configured azure pool would not have and consequently wouldn't be able to build the project. It isn't an option to remove the 3rd party dependencies unfortunately. See self hosted agents; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this, I'm well familiar with the self-hosted agents especially for the 3rd party dependencies. Placing the term Azure in front of self-hosted got me confused. May I suggest that you alter this to Self-hosted Windows agent (for Azure pipelines)?

Comment: what happens when you kick off a build manually on that VM?

Comment: @promicro, see test 5 in updated OP. It almost works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I wasn't able to determine the cause for the mis-used paths and ended up creating a new VM from a clean OS image, then installing VS2019 and VS2022.

While this ultimately worked, I did note that when the VM was configured to connect to the Azure agent pool, and the MSBuild task specified the version to use (17), the use of the command line switch `/p:VisualStudioVersion=16.0`, caused it to overwrite `msbuild`s own settings.

In my case, I needed other assemblies to compile a `.sqlproj`. These were (correctly) stored in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets`.

This file then referenced the required assemblies in v17 of `msbuild`. However, the switch caused it to modify the settings stored in its configuration file and overwrite the `\17\` part of the path to the assemblies and replace it with `\16\` instead. This then broke the build as the resolved path didn't point to a valid location.

While not the original issue, it did demonstrate that there's definitely...odd...path manipulation going on within `msbuild` as it resolves them.

Answer (score 2):

What versions of Visual Studio are all installed on this VM?
A customer had similar issues and they reinstalled visual studio.

Can you check the version that is setup at the Agent Capabilities :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52828794/8843952

Furthermore this looks at bit the same:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/azure-pipelines-msbuild-vstest-cannot-find-msbuild/937549

**update**

Since you think VS2022 install has messed up your VM, these link could be usefull in the search for MSBuild:

- https://github.com/Microsoft/vswhere/wiki/Find-MSBuild
- https://gist.github.com/nicolasdao/b1623cb3220be3b6dc8fe04b2b2bfe32

**Additional advice from wade Zhou msft**

upgrade to vsbuild: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/vsbuild-v1?view=azure-pipelines

FYI just checked at the customer where we did the reinstall, for all yaml pipelines they're using vsbuild now. This might do the trick for you too.

Comment: Several versions, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, and 17. Uninstalling the older ones isn't much of an option as we need repeatable historical builds. I'm thinking I may need to setup a new agent/VM

Comment: An interesting additional point is that this VM worked fine with all versions installed up to 16. The act of installing VS2022 Enterprise seems to have done something to cause the agent to only use MSBuild v12. Uninstalling VS2022 has left the VM in the same broken state of using v12.

Comment: You could always try to install a second agent on the same vm, see what it does. But I just ran diagnostics and nothing really point to msbuild from the agent side

Comment: Am I missing something - you have this for the version; "MSBuild Version: 17.0", but then use the path to the 12.0 MSBuild.exe - "Path to MSBuild: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe"

Shouldn't that be "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\17.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" or is it something like; "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe" - I'm not sure since we use the Visual Studio build task in what few classic build pipelines we have left and it has a dropdown to which VS version to use.

Comment: @Tom, precisely, it *should* be using version `17`. I have no idea what's overriding it to use `12`

Comment: @promicro, yes I'd started with a different VM originally and had thought it was the agent config, but nothing there explicitly references the MSBuild version that I can see. It seems to be something in the chain that's picking the incorrect version for the build but I'm not sure what.

Comment: @DiskJunky did any of the links in my edit be of help?

Comment: @promicro, they have, thank you! I'll start back in on things in the morning and will update my post with any findings. Much appreciated!

Comment: Sorry - I was confused as to where you got that image above. I thought that's what you set it at. Can you show us what the task looks like? I'm assuming you're building this via classic build pipeline. Perhaps the path to msbuild should be something like "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe" Or you could uninstall and re-install the agent to pick up any new capabilities. Not sure if just updating the agent picks it up...I find it easier to just re-install it.

Comment: As per the MSBuild screenshot, you have specified the `path of msbuild`, please make sure you have `17.0` msbuild installed on the agent, and specify `correct path` in the task. In addition, you can try with `Visual studio Build`  task which is recommended to be instead of Msbuild task.

Comment: @wadezhou-MSFT, the screenshot isn't me picking v`12` of the build. That's the output of the log after the build breaks. V17 is installed, and I've updated my post with the results of the suggestions here. Nothing has worked, though hardcoding the build path did at least change the error message.

Comment: Hi @DiskJunky, if you build another sample project on the agent with same task, will it force to use the V12 version?

Comment: Hi @DiskJunky, as per the Update 5 result in the description, it appears the version 12 is declared in the project which caused local build failed as well. Please fix the code, then check the again.

Comment: @wadezhou-MSFT, I haven't yet had a chance to t ry building a different, smaller solution, but I'll do that when I'm back at work. As for the other comment, the project file it's pulling in is `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.NETFramework.props`, which is part of the MSBuild installation, not my solution.